# Is there a way to export a unique scss file to modular css files?

Tags: css, performance, sass

I was wondering if there's anyway to have all my CSS into **one** Sass file, and compile it into many css files, like one per page/template/widget. Maybe there is a webpack plugin who does it?

The ultimate goal of this is to optimize my CSS performances without manage 10-15 css files.

I think of something like :

```
@file main.css{
    html{
      //Some CSS
    }

    header{
      //Some CSS
    }
}

@file home.css{
    .homeContent{
      //Some CSS
    }
}
```

Will compile into two files : main.css and home.css.

Is anybody have a tool for this? Or what techniques are you using to manage your CSS?

Comment: The purpose of webpack is to make one file of many files. However you can set multiple entry and thus output paths

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see an advantage here?  One file with the contents of multiple files just so you can have have multiple files output.  I can understand not wanting to manage 15 source files, but that seems much better than the added complexity of one file that actually represents 15 compiled files.

That single file would be huge an difficult to find things in.  Given your code example, you seem to want to organize the code by files anyway.

It's possible to organize SCSS into components instead of by "pages" (depending on your actual needs of course).  If an SCSS file is prefixed with an underscore `_home.scss` it will not generate a CSS file.  You can use this to your advantage to organize things and then have a file that outputs exactly what you need by importing the needed components.

- `components/_tables.scss`
- `components/_buttons.scss`
- `components/_images.scss`
- etc.

Then in `home.scss` just import what you need:

```
@import 'components/tables;
@import 'components/buttons;

#home-content {
  background: red;
  //whatever else...
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. My team and I used to work with a single scss file so, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: if you have a single monolithic file is any language, you're doing something wrong.  I **highly** recommend splitting it up into small & manageable files that only do one thing.  I also highly recommend using `stylelint` to help ensure you're writing clean code. https://stylelint.io/